# Symfony PropertyAccessor setValue gives NoSuchPropertyException on objects

Tags: php, symfony, properties

In my code I want to extract messsages and fields from constraint violations
into arrays. The `PropertyAccess` has `setValue` for this. It works on array keys but does not work on object attributes.

Using `setValue` on object attributes results in

```
fatal error: Uncaught Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\Exception
\NoSuchPropertyException: Cannot write property "first_name" to an array. 
Maybe you should write the property path as "[first_name]" instead?
```

To my understanding, `PropertyAccess` unifies access to both arrays and objects. Why is then `setValue` not working on object attributes?

Here is the code snippet:

```
$user = new User('', 'Novak', 'pnovak@examplecom');

$validator =   Validation::createValidatorBuilder()->addXmlMapping('validation.xml')->getValidator();
$violations = $validator->validate($user);

$accessor = PropertyAccess::createPropertyAccessor();

$messages = [];

if (0 === count($violations)) {

    echo 'validation passed';
} else {

    foreach ($violations as $violation) {


        // $messages[$violation->getPropertyPath()] = $violation->getMessage();

        $accessor->setValue($messages,
            $violation->getPropertyPath(),
            $violation->getMessage());
    }

    dump($messages);
}
```

Comment: According the error message, I would tried that : `$accessor->setValue($messages, [$violation->getPropertyPath()], $violation->getMessage());`

Comment: I does not work. It gives this error: `The property path constructor needs a string or an instance of "Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyPath". Got: "array"`

Comment: Hum and like that maybe ? :  `$accessor->setValue($messages, '['.$violation->getPropertyPath().']', $violation->getMessage());`

Comment: This way it is working. But it is kind of a hack, I would expect the processor itself to handle this.